# Is there a way to declare cyclic type aliases in C++

Tags: c++, c++20, typedef, using, type-declaration

I have a piece of code that looks something like

```
class Something {};
using MyUnionType = std::variant<A, B>;
using A = Something;
using B = std::vector<MyUnionType>;
```

but this does not compile, and I get

`error: use of undeclared identifier 'A'` in the declaration of MyUnionType

and `error: use of undeclared identifier 'MyUnionType'` in the declaration of B.

Is there a way to declare these types (aliases) or is C++ not advanced enough to do this?

I have tried to forward-declare A and B as follows

```
class Something {};
class A;
class B;
using MyUnionType = std::variant<A, B>;
using A = Something;
using B = std::vector<MyUnionType>;
```

but this also does not compile.

`error: typedef redefinition with different types ('Something' vs 'A')`

`error: typedef redefinition with different types ('std::vector<MyUnionType>' (aka 'vector<variant<A, B>>') vs 'B')`

When I try to move the declaration of MyUnionType to the bottom and forward-declare MyUnionType instead, I get a similar error.

Comment: *Why* do you want/need this? Just curious.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I am writing a short parser and I have 5 types of expressions. Each of them can contain sub-expressions, and the expression type is a union of these 5 types.

Comment: `using MyUnionType = std::variant<Something, std::vector<MyUnionType>>;` I do not see how that is possible.

Comment: @KamilCuk I want the other types to still have proper names. In the real code, their definitions are too long to combine them like this. Your suggestion would make it unreadable.

Comment: Type alias is just that - alias. You can alias later, at any time, it's just an alias. The point is, you can't have infinite types or circular types - `using MyUnionType = std::variant<Something, std::vector<MyUnionType>>;` is referencing itself.

Comment: I think the main problem is that you want to use MyUnionType recursively

Comment: `I have tried to forward-declare A and B as follows` `class A` is distinct own type, completely different from `using A`, you can't "forward-declare using", because it's only an alias..

Comment: @Konstantin.Krivyakin it is not a problem, C++ supports recursive type definitions. However, it does cause complications, because C++ has unnecessarily strict rules about the order of type declarations.

Comment: @KamilCuk I know, but I had to at least try something. C++ still does not have good syntax for forward-declaring alias type declarations.

Comment: @Fullfungo: Aliases are *not* "type definitions*. They're aliases; an alternative name for a thing.

Comment: What do you want `MyUnionType` to be an alias for?  As is, it seems like you want an infinitely recursive type.  `MyUnionType` would be an alias for `std::variant<Something, std::vector<std::variant<Something, std::vector<std::variant<...>>>>>` ad infinitum.  C++ does not allow such things.  If you can't write the type without aliases you can't write it with aliases.

Comment: @NicolBolas I have to disagree. `using AliasType = std::variant<int, long>` is a new type, separate from any other; it is not an alternative name for any previously declared type.

Comment: @Fullfungo That's simply wrong. The exact opposite is true. There is only one type `std::variant<int, long>` and `AliasType` is an alias for it, not a distinct type.

Comment: @Fullfungo: Really? Better tell your compiler that: `std::is_same_v<AliasType, std::variant<int, long>>` is `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reference the class itself, you have to define a new type.

```
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
struct Something {};
struct MyUnionType;
using A = Something;
using B = std::vector<MyUnionType>;
struct MyUnionType {
    std::variant<A, B> v;
};
```

You may be interested in some references: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations .

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I found the links helpful, but it is a bit of bummer that C++ still does not have concise type declarations/definitions unlike other modern programming languages.